# Earliest reference for infinitesimal neighborhoods of the diagonal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ho.history-overview

[Where was $I_x/I_x^2$ first introduced? (DG or AG)](https://mathoverflow.net/q/287654/69037) asks about the algebraic cotangent space. The paper [*First neighborhood of the diagonal and geometric distributions*](https://tildeweb.au.dk/au76680/FNDGD.pdf) by Kock claims Grothendieck initiated the study of neighborhoods of the diagonal, later adopted by Malgrange and Kumpera & Spencer.

What is the earliest explicit reference of the *infinitesimal* neighborhoods of the diagonal?

Comment: Are you asking about "neighborhoods of the diagonal" (~tangent bundles) or "higher order neighborhoods of the diagonal" (~jet bundles), as in the first paragraph of Kock's paper? In any case, Kock is certainly not claiming that Grothendieck was the first person to consider a neighboorhood of a diagonal, in any setting.

Comment: @DanPetersen I'm asking about "infinitesimal neighborhoods of the diagonal" as in jet bundles.